# String breaks in new line in source, not in browser

Tags: javascript, line, break

I'm working on a school project where I have to extract tweets from Twitter, into my database, and after that analyse them with JavaScript. Now I'm at the following problem with putting them in a JS array.

The 20th result from my DB seems to break into a new line. If I skip it, it works fine, but once this gets added. It will break into a new line. I've echo'ed this particular tweet separately in a different file. The output on the webpage is as follows:

```
@HARDWELL Awesome!! Happy Friday :) http://t.co/uLbm9QvNUM
```

When I press CTRL+U the Source looks at follows:

```
@HARDWELL Awesome!! Happy Friday :)
http://t.co/uLbm9QvNUM
```

This would supposedly break my new Array () code since javascript suddenly gets into a new line, so stops continuing on the array.

I tried escaping, htmlspecialchars, and all of the other code but nothing seems to work.

What code makes me able to remove these random line breaks, there is nu /n or /r or whatsoever..

this is how my array looks like because of it:

```
var tweetArray = new Array("@HARDWELL great night. Love to do it again http://t.co/j4dtyTQDt8", "i think @HARDWELL is going to be one of the most influential people in the 2010's &amp;amp;amp; 2020's!!!", "@HARDWELL is amazing!!", "dying to hear how @HARDWELL felt behind the DJ both at @ultramusic?people fordayzzz there to watch you kill it #missionaccomplished", "@HARDWELL @DyroMusic @RevealedRec #revealedcontest http://t.co/yAW4bEaGKA", "@HARDWELL PLEASE NOTICE ME I LOVE YU SO FUCKING MUCH COME TO VENEZUELA NOTICE ME PLEAAAAASR YOU ARE MY IDOL", "RT @BigNoseFaggot: @HARDWELL @DyroMusic @RevealedRec #revealedcontest http://t.co/zOc6WLGiRd", "Listening to @HARDWELL tomorrowland set got me buzzzzzzing! Going next year ðŸ’¯", "RT @HARDWELL: We're the lucky ones...", "@HARDWELL @DyroMusic @RevealedRec #revealedcontest http://t.co/zOc6WLGiRd", "#nowwatching @HARDWELL LIVE AT Miami UMF 2013", "A new favorite: Hardwell - Spaceman Naffz Remix [OUT NOW] by @hardwell http://t.co/fkzRC4XSdN on #SoundCloud", "@WetRepublic in #April with @CalvinHarris @nervomusic @HARDWELL @deadmau5 &amp;amp;amp; @steveaoki http://t.co/MxWSzw3O1s", "#NP @HARDWELL Forever in my mind #ultramusic", "@DANNICdj @revealedrec @HARDWELL HUGE track, heard it at UMF! #RevealedBombFactory", "RT @HARDWELL: The soundtrack of your nightlife!", "@HARDWELL follow me!!!", "@HARDWELL great!!! http://t.co/g86s9DJFLK", "RT @Est_C: Never too early for a @HARDWELL podcast #Armin #ThisIsWhatItFeelsLike", "@hardwell @avicii @kaskade 1 2 3 sets of ultra", "@HARDWELL Awesome!! Happy Friday :
http://t.co/uLbm9QvNUM");
```

The last part isn't on the same line, causing my code to break I suppose.

Google Closure errors:

JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. unterminated string literal at line 3 character 1530
...l @avicii @kaskade 1 2 3 sets of ultra", "@HARDWELL Awesome!! Happy Friday :)
                                            ^
JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. missing ) after argument list at line 4 character 0
http://t.co/uLbm9QvNUM");
^
JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. syntax error at line 4 character 4
http://t.co/uLbm9QvNUM");
    ^

---

So far I found out, that when I manually put a backspace between the empty space of ) and h (where the line breaks) it solves the issue for this particular row. It seems the twitter API saves people who put 'new lines' in their tweets.. and I think that is the cause, but how could they be invisible my question is then? Does anyone know how I could remove 'enters' from the php string?

Comment: As it seems as though the linebreak is not the cause, I've removed my answer. Do you actually get a JS error message?

Comment: I've run it into google closure, which gives these 3 errors: they are in the opening post

Comment: When i put the last line, which is one line below, on the same line as the rest, the code is successfull according to Google Closure..

Comment: Let me ask you this, is this the first tweet in your list that has a URL in it?

Comment: New line breaks inside strings are illegal in JavaScript put a backslash in front of the new line like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j77Hu/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the ) on the happy face is closing the array and makes the new line.

Comment: I've removed that once, it wasn't the case. I went into my DB, and put in a backspace at the moment the line broke. Just a simple backspace between the empty space of the ) and the h, and it solved the issue. The problem is that I can't manually filter out every tweet that has this issue. I suppose this is because people push the enter button in a tweet and this gets saved, how can I remove these kind of 'enter button' line breaks with PHP?

Comment: Removing white spaces with \s seemed to help for 9/10th of the cases, cant seem to remove the last 10% of these.. what else could help?

Comment: try using the trim function. Here you can see an example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php